# Jenkins trigger a job from API

Tags: html, jenkins

I m actually trying to make some API calls to jenkins to trigger a build.

Actually, I m facing two problems :

**In a non-restricted** environnement, where I don't need to be connected to trigger a job, I should send a POST request on :

```
http://address/job/jobId/build?delay=0sec
```

When making this, I get the following output telling me that I don't have a token value :

```
<html>

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>

        <title>Error 401 Invalid password/token for user: </title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>

        <p>Problem accessing /job/Di%20Injector/build. Reason:

            <pre>    Invalid password/token for user: </pre>
        </p>
        <hr />
        <i>
            <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
        </i>
        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                

        <br/>                                                


    </body>

</html>
```

*Where could I get this information ?*

**In a restricted** environnement, I have to login before make any thing like getting job, or trigger new build. The fact is that I don't know, and I can't find the url / verb / params to send to the server to get an access right.

Can you help me with this too ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is to generate an API token for your Jenkins user (or the Jenkins build user).

Go to the following link for your user:

```
http://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/user/YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID/configure
```

Copy the user_id and token from this section:

[image]

And launch the following command to trigger a build:

```
curl -X POST http://YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID:YOUR_API_TOKEN@YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JENKINS_JOB/build
```

I did a quick test on my https Jenkins server.

Without the token, I got this message:

```
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

With the user_id/token, the build is OK with the curl command :)

Comment: This answers looks great, but I always have an error authentication is required :-/

Comment: Let's open a chat to discuss of that :)

Comment: Full example with `crumb` can be found here: [Running jenkins jobs via command line](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/jnrg/running-jenkins-build-via-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

If you are building with parameters then here it is:

Lets say your jenkins build accept two parameters and you want to make the api call using shell script:

You can put following command in shell script:

> curl -X POST --data "package_name=ABC.tar.gz" --data "release_notes=none" --data "delay=0sec" https://USERID:TOKEN@JENKINS_URL/job/SOMETHING/SOMETHING/SOMETHING//buildWithParameters

Just use the address bar to make the link. Make sure the link ends with **buildWithParameters**