# Executing multiple jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

Can someone please let me know how i can trigger multiple Jenkins jobs? We have 5-6 jobs that we need to trigger manually post some technical upgrades. We are having to navigate to these jobs manually and click on 'Build'. Is there anyway i can create a new job or shell script that will help me in triggering all of these jobs with a single click/run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in both ways that you mentioned. Creating a new job that will run all these other jobs as downstream jobs is the fastest and easiest.

To do this, create a new job, and if you are using declarative Jenkins, then specify the jobs to be triggered:

```
stage ('trigger-multiple-jobs') {
    parallel {
        stage ('first job') {
            steps {
                build([
                    job       : 'JobName',
                    wait      : false,
                    parameters: [
                        string(name: 'PARAM_1', value: "${PARAM_1}")
                    ]
                ])
            }
        }
        stage ('second job') {
            steps {
                build([
                    job       : 'JobName2',
                    wait      : false
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can alternatively create a freestyle job, navigate down to the `Trigger downstream jobs` section, and set the jobs you want to be triggered from the drop down.

If you want to use a shell script, then you can trigger the jobs using API calls. This is described well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634247/3730626).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach will be creating a new pipeline which will trigger other pipelines.
You can also make stages parallel to faster execution if order is not issue.
You can find detailed answer and approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295773/how-to-use-a-fileparametervalue-in-a-jenkins-2-pipeline)